# How to calculate confidence intervals for a vector?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a vector:

```
vector <- c(12, 17, 24, 35, 23, 34, 56)
```

How to calculate confidence intervals (90%, 99%, 95%) for this vector in R?

This is example of result I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wau32.jpg)

Comment: Confidence intervals can be defined/calculated for a specific metric (population parameter) you have in mind (such as the mean) and not for a set of values (such as a vector).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a function that will calculate your confidence interval according to the t-distribution:

```
confidence_interval <- function(vector, interval) {
  # Standard deviation of sample
  vec_sd <- sd(vector)
  # Sample size
  n <- length(vector)
  # Mean of sample
  vec_mean <- mean(vector)
  # Error according to t distribution
  error <- qt((interval + 1)/2, df = n - 1) * vec_sd / sqrt(n)
  # Confidence interval as a vector
  result <- c("lower" = vec_mean - error, "upper" = vec_mean + error)
  return(result)
}
```

And example usage for your provided vector and intervals:

```
> vector <- c(12, 17, 24, 35, 23, 34, 56)
> confidence_interval(vector, 0.90)
   lower    upper 
17.97255 39.45602 
> confidence_interval(vector, 0.95)
   lower    upper 
15.18797 42.24060 
> confidence_interval(vector, 0.99)
    lower     upper 
 8.219946 49.208626
```

And [this is the tutorial](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/confidence.html) from which I developed this method.

Comment: You should be using the t-distribution not normal distribution for such a small number of observations.

Comment: @AlexW thanks, you're right. I've amended my function by swapping the normal distribution for the t.

Comment: You may also do:  > t.test(vector,conf.level = 0.95)

Comment: Awesome awesome.