# Calculate number of datapoints that fall into 95%CI of another independent distribution with different N

Tags: r, math, statistics

Imagine we have two samples A and B that we he have obtained independently using a simulator and an experiment. They have different N size. For example:

```
A <- c(1,1.23,1.56,1.43,1.9,0.9)
B <- c(1, 3, 4, 3.2, 1.2, 1.6, 1.8, 1, 0.7, 1.2,  2, 2, 1, 4, 5.4)
```

Using R, we want to know how many data-points of B fall into the 95%CI of A.

I am pretty sure that there is a test that calculates this statistic automatically, but I couldn't find a duplicate for this question in the forum, nor any statistical comparison to easily check this when it comes to compare two samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing (copying) massively from this answer: [How to calculate confidence intervals for a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612153/how-to-calculate-confidence-intervals-for-a-vector). We first need to calculate the CIs of vector A using a t-distribution and then we can check which values of B fall between these

```r
A <- c(1,1.23,1.56,1.43,1.9,0.9)
B <- c(1, 3, 4, 3.2, 1.2, 1.6, 1.8, 1, 0.7, 1.2,  2, 2, 1, 4, 5.4)

confidence_interval <- function(vector, interval = 0.95) {
  # Standard deviation of sample
  vec_sd <- sd(vector)
  # Sample size
  n <- length(vector)
  # Mean of sample
  vec_mean <- mean(vector)
  # Error according to t distribution
  error <- qt((interval + 1)/2, df = n - 1) * vec_sd / sqrt(n)
  # Confidence interval as a vector
  result <- c("lower" = vec_mean - error, "upper" = vec_mean + error)
  return(result)
}

CIs <- confidence_interval(A)

length(B[between(B, CIs[1], CIs[2])])
```

Hopefully this works.